# Remove a tag from photo, when somebody tagged my Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Somebody tagged my Facebook page into a photo which is offensive.

I have no option to remove the tag (at least from what I see). I did report the photo to Facebook and they say they don't violate the terms.

I blocked the user, but still, the photo is still there and my Facebook page tag is in the photo.

What can I do? How can I remove the tag?

Comment: Did you try this https://www.facebook.com/help/140906109319589 ?